# Spring-xd hdfs sink- Error Creating bean

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-yarn, spring-xd

I am getting the following exception when deploying stream with `hdfs` as sink in `spring-xd`.
 Error creating bean with name `'hadoopConf   iguration':` `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf`

I have my spring-xd app running on yarn successfully. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the configuration in siteMapreduceAppClassPath in servers.yml. The classpath should include the path of hadoop-core jar, as the jar is not included the app it is giving NoClassDefFoundError.